# Where is the jar files cached for Java Web Start/JNLP applications?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Where is the jar files cached for Java Web Start/JNLP applications?

Comment: At least in Windows, it will not store the jar with the original name (not even with .jar file extension). Check the time stamp and file size to get your requested jar files.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends... on your OS and virtual machine, e.g.:

- with a Sun JDK 1.5 and Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\javaws\`
- with a Sun JDK 1.6 and Vista: `C:\Users\userid\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0`
- with a Sun JDK 1.6 and GNU/Linux: `/home/userid/.java/deployment/cache/6.0`
- with a Sun JDK 1.6 and Mac OS X: `~/Library/Caches/Java/cache/6.0/`

With a Sun JDK 6, this can be configured through the Java Control Panel (Temporary Internet Files *Settings* in the *General* tab).

Answer (score 10):

On Windows Vista or 7, it's in `%AppData%\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the file extension is not jar. So, you may check the file size and find it somehow.

Comment: Don't works but `%HOMEPATH%\appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache` is ok. %AppData% go to `%HOMEPATH%\appdata\Roaming`

Answer (score 3):

There is more to JNLP than just Sun's implementation.

The OpenJDK packages shipped by Debain, for instance, bundle [netx](http://jnlp.sourceforge.net/netx/), which stores its files in `~/.netx/cache/`. The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#External_links) has a list of  known implementations other than Sun's.

You really shouldn't rely on this path being well-known in your application's code.

Comment: If you happen to be using netx.jar from icedteaweb you can specify ` -Xclearcache` command line param

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu and other debian based linux distros using icedtea: `/home/${USER}/.icedtea/cache`

In case you want just to clear the cache `javaws -uninstall` won’t work. `javaws -Xclearcache` does the job for icedtea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are also interested in the content of the jars in the JNLP cache you might want to use the following script (tested on Mac OS X) to examine the jar files with jar -tvf:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#   Author: WF
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517350/where-is-the-jar-files-cached-for-java-web-start-jnlp-applications

os=`uname`
case $os in 
 # Mac OS X
 Darwin*)
   jnlpcache="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0"
     ;;
 *)
   echo "to make this script work for $os you might want to edit it" 1>&2
   echo "and add a case option" 1>&2
     echo "please copy your result back to the stackoverflow answer" 1>&2
     exit 1
     ;;
esac

cd "$jnlpcache"
tmp="/tmp/jnlp$$"
for f in `find . -type f`
do
    jar -tvf $f 2>/dev/null > $tmp
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "found jar $f"
        echo "it contains: "
      cat $tmp
    fi
done
rm $tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily view or clear (uninstall) your Java WebStart applications. This can be done using the Java Control Panel as described below.http://www.ngs.ac.uk/ukca/certificates/certwizard/clearwebstartcache