# Running a webstart java .jnlp program after backing it up

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a java webstart program which is unique. A lot of people use this program and I am concerned it will one day disappear as the creator can't be contacted.

Using 
[Where is the jar files cached for Java Web Start/JNLP applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517350/where-is-the-jar-files-cached-for-java-web-start-jnlp-applications) & [Clearing the Java WebStart Cache](http://www.ngs.ac.uk/ukca/certificates/certwizard/clearwebstartcache), I was able to view the jnlp file which references the .jar files. I was then able to wget these and back them up. But how do I run them now? Perhaps I could mirror the program but there's no licensing info that I can see

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/" href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/HBTM2.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>HollowBoard Template Maker</title>
    <vendor>JedAil</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://http://jedail.free.fr/"/>
    <description>Hollow Board Template Maker</description>
    <description kind="short">Hollow Board Template Maker</description>
    <icon href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/hbtm.png" kind="default"/>
    <shortcut online="true" install="false">
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.5+"/>
    <jar href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/hbtm/hbtm.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/hbtm/vecmath.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/hbtm/kernel.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://jedail.free.fr/programs/hbtm/iText-2.1.7.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="application.HBTM.HBTMFrame"/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1):

A look at the manifest shows the main class fully qualified name as `application.HBTM.HBTMFrame` and that the code is signed, but that it does not specify the class-path.

So something like this might do (easier/shorter when executed from the one directory where all the Jars are):

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:path application.HBTM.HBTMFrame
```

- `Xbootclasspath`: there used to be a `classpath` option up to & inlcuding Java 7, but the [Java 8 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) don't mention it. It looks as though using the `Xbootclasspath` is now the only option for adding the other jars to the run-time class-path of an app., short of editing the manifest to include the class path (the preferred option for a while now).
- `path`: list every jar, separated by semi-colon (`;` for Windows at least).

Note that this will definitely fail if the app. uses the services provided in the JNLP API, which is only available to apps. launched using the Java Web Start client. Very few apps. make use of this API.