# Where Jar file stores files After running it

Tags: java, jar, dropwizard

Yet I used to believe jar files stores files under target directory. I used to  run dropwizard jar file

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup java -jar abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > nohup.out &
```

on  ubuntu server.

Today i have deleted nohup.out file, jar file and even target file !!.Process still  is running and webservices are running as usual. The process stops after entering kill  -9 pid command.

I have also followed this article but no trace i have found of embedded class files inside jar.

[Where is the jar files cached for Java Web Start/JNLP applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517350/where-is-the-jar-files-cached-for-java-web-start-jnlp-applications)

Please elaborate  where files embedded in jar get stored  after running it.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why do you think the class files are supposed to be saved anywhere outside the jar?

Comment: Actually i think if i have  deleted jar file  then process should be stopped .From where it is getting all the class files ? How it is handling rest services ? There must be some source from where it is getting class files and methods.

Comment: In Unix/Linux, if any process has an open reference to a file, then removing the file doesn't actually delete it until the process closes it. So if you deleted it from outside the process, the file is still on disk.

Comment: Thanks !! So if location of file on the disk can be known ? If it can  be known then if we can change the file and we don't need to deploy the jar again and again. I think i need to study more on parent ,child and daemon  process :) and  how it is working.    Sorry i cannot upvote you as not have enough reputation.  Many many thanks to you!!

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Changing a file while it is open is a recipe for errors. And most of the relevant classes are probably cached in memory.